# Simple short, overvoltage and reverse polarity protection

Tags: power-supply, protection, zener, schottky

I am looking for a simple way to protect the 3.3 V power supply to which the MCU and other peripherals are connected. The protection is supposed to be against short circuit, overvoltage and reverse polarity.

Do you see any faults in the schematic below?

**Assumptions:**

1. The maximum current consumption of the circuit is 120 mA.
2. F1 is a fast fuse, it turns on at 250 mA.
3. D3 is a zener diode with 3.6 V zener voltage and 3 W power. The maximum current it can pass is 830 mA, so the fuse should switch on before the diode burns out.

[image: Scheme]

Comment: I note the lack of anything here, let alone a discussion of current foldback or crowbars, which in days long since gone were a staple for linear supplies. Perhaps you may need to write more.

Comment: @jonk The most important requirement for my protection circuit is its simplicity and low price. I do not want to use a crowbar circuit or an IC like eFuse because they require more components or are more expensive. The diagram above is the simplest idea I could think of, but I have never used it in practice yet, hence my question. It is possible that for some reason this is not the optimal solution with the assumptions of simplicity and price.

Comment: Then I don't have anything to add. I don't see enough of your mind to offer either constructive criticism or support. Sorry to bother you. Others may chip in, though.

Comment: @jonk There must have been a misunderstanding, I am open to criticism (that's why this topic was created) but so far I have not received any specific feedback on the schematic.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that you weren't open to criticism. Please don't imagine that I feel you don't want any. You are posting, after all, as you say. I was just telling you that *I* don't have enough of what's in your mind to offer any. Different things, entirely. It's about me, not you.

Comment: @jonk What information would be necessary for you to tell me more about the subject?

Comment: If you feel you have provided everything necessary -- and I can't speak to others' feelings about this -- then perhaps you have and others will respond well. I don't have motivation to slowly unravel things via a protracted (and perhaps uncomfortable) discussion of my thoughts. But that's probably just me and I'm just not in the right frame of mind.

Comment: @jonk Ok I understand. I am trying to describe the problem in a very minimal way and it is possible that some of the information needed to give a definite answer was missing. The best solution will be to actually make this circuit and test it in practice, because if no one has answered so far, it is unlikely to happen yet.